# Target not found when using ld to link two files

Tags: ld

I am trying to link two files, one complied with nasm from an assembly file and the other compiled with gcc from a C file, using a custom file. The command executed is this one:

```
ld -m elf_i386 -T link.ld -o kernel kasm.o kc.o
```

However, it returns this error:

```
ld: target elf12-i386 not found
```

I am running a Debian 3.16.39 i686

Comment: from the man page for `ld` : -m emulation
    Emulate the emulation linker. You can list the available emulations with the --verbose or -V options.   It would appear that you don't have an elf-i386 emulator

Comment: `elf12-i386` is an argument for `TARGET()` command in your ld script. Don't you should use `elf32-i386` instead?